# spring boot RequestParam Class always null

Tags: spring

I'm using Spring boot

My Problem when I post form Classes(VehicleBrand,etc.) always null but others (vinNumber,plate) is not null..

How Can I Fix it..

Thanks

Controller

```
    @Transactional
    @PostMapping
    String vehicleAddSubmit(
            @RequestParam String plate,
            @RequestParam String vinNumber,
            @RequestParam VehicleBrand vehicleBrand
    ){
        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
        vehicle.setVehicleBrand(vehicleBrand);
        vehicle.setEngineNumber(engineNumber);
        vehicle.setVinNumber(vinNumber);
    }
```

View

```
        <form th:attr="action=@{${#mvc.url('VC#vehicleAddSubmit').build()}}"  method="post" class="form-horizontal">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="plate" placeholder="Plaka"/>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vinNumber" placeholder="Şase"/>
         <select id="vBrand" name="vehicleBrand" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Marka Seçin</option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option th:each="vBrand : ${vBrands}"                                                         
                  th:value="${vBrand.id}"                                                            
                  th:text="${vBrand.name}">
            </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ReqeustParam` work differently. Here is snippet from Spring Documentation about `@RequestParam`

> Annotation which indicates that a method parameter should be bound to a web request parameter.

For POST requests, you should have `@RequestBody` to get the Model/Object. Spring will do the conversion for you. Again, another snippet from Spring Documentation about `@RequestBody`

> Annotation indicating a method parameter should be bound to the body of the web request. The body of the request is passed through an HttpMessageConverter to resolve the method argument depending on the content type of the request.

```
@PostMapping
String vehicleAddSubmit(@Request VehicleForm vehicleform){
    //do that you need to do with this vehicle form here.
}
```

Include all the fields that you need in this VehicleForm.

For further knowledge, please see Spring Documentation.